# Asp.NET MVC DisplayName is not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model, razor-pages

I have added the display name however it is not showing up when I run the application.

Employee.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

 
[Required]
[DisplayName("First Name & Last Name")]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

AddEmployee.cshtml

```
@model employee_creation.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Employee";
}

 <label asp-for="FullName" class="form-label font-w600"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-label-tag-helper) it looks like you should use `[Display(Name = "First Name & Last Name")]` instead.
In many scenarios these attributes works the same but we need to remember that those are two different types - and I guess Tag helpers does not support both

Comment: I had tried that as well and it didn't work

Comment: what does it mean "not showing up" then? Is that not present in html or you cannot see it on page? Maybe label is a part of component which is hidden or something? Did you try to inspect actual html?

Comment: The text that is in asp-for="FullName" is what is shown. So it displays  FullName instead of  First Name & Last Name

Answer (score 0):

```
<label asp-for="FullName" class="form-label font-w600"></label>
```

will always show "**First Name & Last Name**". To get the actual value inside label use below code i.e.

```
<label class="form-label font-w600">@Model.FullName</label>
```